# base64_encode weird behavior

Tags: php, base64

I'm doing something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE user='$user';
$myrow = fetchRow() // previously I inserted a pass to the db using base64_encode ex: WRM2gt3R=

$somepass = base64_encode($_POST['password']);

if($myrow[1] != $somepass) echo 'error';
else echo 'welcome';
```

Im always getting error, I even echo $somepass and $myrow[1] they are the same, but still error. What Am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Please provide some information about what $myrow and $_POST actually contain (var_dump($myrow); and var_dump($_POST);)

Comment: var_dump($somepass);
var_dump($myrow);

and paste the output into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `var_dump` instead of echo - maybe one of them has a space or newline at the start/end.

Edit:

You must be storing it as CHAR(40): `A fixed-length string that is always right-padded with spaces to the specified length when stored`

Use VARCHAR or `trim()`

Answer (score 0):

If $myrow[1] is actually the correct password in base64-encoding, I don't see any errors.

Try this ind the end:

```
echo "<br />$myrow[1] != $somepass";
```

What does it say?

And by the way: I don't see any reason to base64-encode the passwords. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

I think somehow if I do a var_dump() I get:

string(40) "YWRraM2= "
string(8) "YWRraM2="

seems like somehow if I insert the data into the db using the console its adding an extra space to the pass field.

myplacedk: is there any reason why I should not be doing it? I thought it will add an extra leyer of security?

Comment: What database? What column type are you using for the password field?

Comment: A reversible function is no better than plaintext.  You may want to look into the crypt() function instead: http://www.php.net/crypt

Answer (score 0):

This encoding does two things:

1. It adds code, making it more complex and easier to make errors
2. If you view your database on your screen, and someone looks over your shoulder, the passwords may be a bit harder to remember.

So no, it doesn't really add any security. It's just an encoding, it's easy to decode.

Maybe you are mistaking it for md5-hashing or something like that.

Playing around is great, but when it comes to security, I really recommend not using something you don't understand. In the long run, it will do more damage than good.

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

- From your comments elsewhere, I guess that the problem with the current code is that  your database field is CHAR(40). A CHAR field always has a fixed size. Try changing the database field type to VARCHAR instead of CHAR.
- Using base64_encode before storing in a database is nowhere near secure. Good practice is storing only a one-way hash of the password in the database -- typically md5 or (better) sha1. Then, when the user wants to log in, use the same hash-function on the provided password, and then compare the two hashes. 
  This has the added benefit of working with passwords longer than 40 characters too.
  A sha1 or md5-hash always takes a fixed amount of space, so if you go this route, you don't have to switch your database column to VARCHAR :)